# Node.js Updating MySql timestamp

Tags: mysql, node.js

So i do a simple query like so:

```
connection.query("UPDATE workers SET timestamp='"+thedate+"' WHERE id = " + id,function(err,upres){
    connection.release();
    if(!err) {
      console.log('updated record')
      console.log(upres);
    }

})
```

console.log reveals the data format as: 2015-04-02 19:29:14

And if i debug the SQL statement, that turns out to be:

```
UPDATE workers SET timestamp='2015-04-02 21:31:16' WHERE id = 3;
```

However, when i list the data, the output is:

```
[{"id":3,"worker":"John Doe","timestamp":"2015-04-01T22:00:00.000Z","duration":30}]
```

This is way off compared to the time that is being reported?

What is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not know how MySQL is turning your VARCHAR into a date. There are a lot of configuration options. It would be better to use the `STR_TO_DATE` function to circumvent all of the assumptions. Here is a link to the docs for [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

As a side note, I would strongly recommend using prepared statements as a way to safeguard your application against errors and sql injection.

EDITS:

In regards to your questions, the column could be `DATETIME`, but your value you are assigning is a `VARCHAR`

'UPDATE workers SET timestamp = ? WHERE id = ?', ['4/2/2015 3:00:00 PM', 3'], [callBackFunction]

Based on what you said about the conversion not working, I am suspicious about the data type for the timestamp column.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE NAME = 'workers'
```

A statement like that should give you all of the information about that column. You could also find this in a GUI, if you have access. There are three different date types in MySQL date, datetime, or timestamp. This is most likely a DATE column, that will not be able to hold the time.

Comment: timestamp field is a DATE field, not a VARCHAR?

Comment: How do i use prepared statements?

Comment: If i do this: 

UPDATE dab_challenge SET timestamp=STR_TO_DATE('"+mysql+"','%d %b %Y %T:%f')  WHERE id = " + id 

then time is reset to 00:00:00

Comment: Neither does this:

UPDATE dab_challenge SET timestamp=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%b %d %Y %h:%i %p') WHERE id = " + id 

Output is still 00:00:00

Comment: It was combination of both:
1. It was a date field
2. I added the params the way you suggested.
Thanks!